# How to manage single domain name with two servers?

Tags: java, node.js, tomcat, server, dns

The issue is this we are having the single domain name but we are having two servers on two different technologies. Example: NodeJS and Tomcat Server. But I want, when user type domain name it should take it to NodeJS server and click on a login button on the site it should be redirected to the tomcat server. But DNS name should not change.

Example:
`Domain Name - example.com`

`1) nodeJs server :: on port 3000` 
`2) Tomcat server :: on port 8080`

When the user visits `example.com`. Node Js should respond. But if I click on the button like login then it should take me to tomcat(URL: example.com/login )

Comment: do you mean you have two web servers hosted on the same host machine?

Comment: Yes, We have a single AWS Server running in Linux and in which Tomcat and Nodejs are running.

Comment: you can redirect with explicit port number `example.com:8080/login`

Comment: But I don't want to add or show the port number in website URL. Any other option, please let me know ??

Answer (score 1):

This is where you might need to use a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) server and configure it to proxy requests to the two application servers. You can configure a reverse proxy server with your path `/login` to call your Tomcat server. I recommend that you use ngnix, but Apache httpd is also popular as well. If you use nginx, your configuration may look somewhat like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain2.com;
    access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

    # pass request to the tomcat server
    location /login {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    # pass request to the node server
    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to specify all the routes, For tomcat as well as NodeJS?

Comment: If it follows a specific patter such as `/nodejs/[anything]` for nodejs service and so on, you should not. Otherwise yes, you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Use subdomains and set your DNS service to point them at the different IP addresses.

example.com > nodeJs IP
login.example.com > Tomcat IP

This avoids showing the port number or anything else like that, the user will just see the word "login" in a different place—
login.example.com instead of example.com/login